# How can i start all of them immediately

Tags: batch-file, cmd

It is pretty newbie question, but very important for me.
I have simple scenario in bat. for economy of my time.

```
start 
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit).lnk"
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2.lnk"
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\A_Byte_of_Python_2.01.pdf"
```

Programs open one after the other with a delay. This is problem. How to run all programms at the same time? Immediately. **In one second.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the usage information for the `Start` command, i.e. `start /?`, you'll note that the first doublequoted command is read as the window title. So to prevent your doublequoted paths being misunderstood as titles, you'd use an actual or empty title.

```sh
@Start "" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit).lnk"
@Start "" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2.lnk"
@Start "" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\A_Byte_of_Python_2.01.pdf"
```

You could even shorten that by changing directory first:

```sh
@CD /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
@Start "" "IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit).lnk"
@Start "" "PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2.lnk"
@Start "" "A_Byte_of_Python_2.01.pdf"
```

Alternatively, you could use a `For` loop:

```sh
@For %%G In ("IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit).lnk","PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2.lnk","A_Byte_of_Python_2.01.pdf") Do @Start "" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\%%~G"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as a guide it gives multiple `starts`

```
rem   comments should begin with rem
rem   note: this file launches all of my favorite apps!
rem   note: replace the names below with your own..

@echo off

   start %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
   start firefox http://google.com/
   start dreamweaver
   start photoshop
   start winamp
   start notes.txt

@echo on
```

yours could look something like this

```
@echo off

start %SystemRoot%\system32\IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit).lnk"
start PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.2.lnk"
start A_Byte_of_Python_2.01.pdf"

@echo on
```

Hopefully this helps with the starts 
The 1 second request well that depends on the script you are using, batch can be super fast and super slow a lot of that has to do with memory (the size of a file), Python and PowerShell are fast tools

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No Problem Hopefully it helps

Comment: In the interest of general improvement, you don't need the `@echo on` lines. echo on/off only matters while the script is running and since there's nothing after `@echo on`, the line serves no purpose.